# Foreach array with keys to filter the output of an array

Tags: php, arrays

I try echoing some data from this array:

```
Array
(
    ['monday'] => Array
        (
            ['start'] => 3
            ['end'] => 7
        )

    ['tuesday'] => Array
        (
            ['start'] => 4
            ['end'] => 8
        )
)
```

with this PHP code:

```
<?php
$data = $_GET['hours'];
foreach($data as $days => $times){
    foreach($times as $time){
        echo $time['start'];
    }
}
?>
```

But this result does show **3748** and not **3** and **4**.

How can I get the start value and the end value **separated** from each other?

Comment: I'm confused. According to what you posted, this shouldn't work at all. You should be getting an error that you're using array access on an integer. Are you sure the array structure you've presented is accurate?

Comment: Why not store the values as a DateTime? Then you can get the day of the year as well and it's a lot less data in your database

Comment: Improved text and title of the post.

Answer (score 0):

Why use 2 foreach? One is just enough. You cycle through the days and print each day start time.

```
foreach($data as $days){
    echo $days['start'];
}
```

--- Edit ---

I run the code with the data you provide me and it works. Check the img bellow.

[image]

Comment: @ Chris it returns empty :(

Comment: @YoeriAchterbergen look at your array structures and chris's implementation. If your code return empty, adjust it accordingly.